# Javascript function to generate all permutations

Tags: javascript

**How to write a function to generate this output.
and what's the term in javascript for such a function?**

Is it javascript recursion? how to write the function and generate an array of objects.

```
const letters = ['A', 'B'];
const numbers = ['1', '2'];
const colors = ['', ''];



let output = [
    {
        "letter": "A", 
        "Number": "1",
        "Color": "",
    },
    {
        "letter": "B", 
        "Number": "1",
        "Color": "",
    },
    {
        "letter": "A", 
        "Number": "2",
        "Color": "",
    },
    {
        "letter": "B", 
        "Number": "2",
        "Color": "",
    },


    {
        "letter": "A", 
        "Number": "1",
        "Color": "",
    },
    {
        "letter": "B", 
        "Number": "1",
        "Color": "",
    },
    ...

]
```

Comment: @CBroe Mathematically speaking permutations are not combinations: in the former, the order matters, but not in the latter. OP wants distinct combinations where the order of letter/number/color does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of getting all permutations of 3 arrays:

```
let a = [1,2]
let b = ['a','b']
let c = ['$','@']

a.forEach((ai)=>{
  b.forEach((bi)=>{
    c.forEach((ci)=>{
      console.log(ai + bi + ci)
    })
  })
})
```

results in

```
"1a$"
"1a@"
"1b$"
"1b@"
"2a$"
"2a@"
"2b$"
"2b@"
...
```

So you can easily adapt it to your use.